# saving images in PHP with variable name

Tags: php

I am currently developing a web application and need some help.

The functionality is the following: A website connected to a mysql database. You need to select two times brand and then products from that brand solved via interlinked dynamic dropdowns. Based on that selections happen two queries selecting color values from the database, showing them in textfields. 
Solved via jquery, PHP and JSON.

Now I have created a section, which will show an image in the color from the selected RGB values from the DB. PHP needs to create the JPG image using the RGB values from the DB and save the image on the server.

When I implement imagecreate in php and hand over the path to jquery to allocate it to a '"#target", I get the issues.

I considered two ways:
a) generate image on the fly, name it 1.jpg and overwrite the image in every instance. Then I run into issues with the browser cache, loading the previous image although the new image is already stored in the folder.

b) generate new images and save them for better performance named with the RGB values (i.e 151|50|22.jpg) and load if already existing, create if not, but there I cannot save the path when a variable is in the imagejpeg() function in PHP?

I can save i)a combination of path elements and a string '1.jpg' and ii)a path made from a pure string but not a path made from a combination of text and a variable carrying the right image name. 
Propably it is done with right escaping of the variable???

> Errors are:
>   Warning: imagejpeg(images\rgb\225|151|169.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\COLOMETRIX\get_swatch_1a.php on line 39

*{"decision":"images\rgb\225|151|169.jpg"}* this is the Json output

Code is a follows:

```
<?php
$prod1 = $_GET['q'];
include('db_config.php');

// clear variables
$decision='';
$data=''; 

// select dataset  
$result=$db->query("SELECT R, G, B, Get_Col, Selection 
                    FROM farbdatenbank.farbdatenbank 
                    WHERE Name ='".$prod1."' ")
            or die($db->error);
$datensatz=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// define paths and filename
$file=$datensatz['Get_Col'];
$filename=$file.".jpg"; 
$path_rgb='images'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'rgb'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename;

if($datensatz['Selection'] == "Excel"){ 
    // get color values
    $R=$datensatz['R'];
    $G=$datensatz['G'];
    $B=$datensatz['B']; 

    //check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($path_rgb) == true) {   
        $decision=$path_rgb;        
    }
    else
    {   
        // create new image 
        $im1=imagecreatetruecolor(150, 70);
        $colim1=imagecolorallocate($im1, $R, $G, $B);
        imagefill($im1,0,0,$colim1);
        $old =  'images'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'rgb'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'zzz.jpg';   
        imagejpeg($im1,$path_rgb,100);
        $decision=$path_rgb;    
    } 
}   
Else 
{   
    $decision='images'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'pics'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename;    
}
// build output array and encode in JSON format 
$data=array("decision"=>$decision);
echo json_encode($data);
mysqli_close($db);  
?>
```

Thanks for your time

Michael

Comment: What exactly is the problem here - writing to the proper files? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: **To the UPVoter's**. Just because the question is `long and winding` does not make it part of the `yellow brick road`!

Comment: I dont think the pipe character `|` is valid in a file or directory name

Comment: What is `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` set to in your code